# How to get both (plus and minus) square roots

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, sqrt

I want to find both of the square roots of a number using python. My simple code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
x = 4.0
print 'Square roots of',x,'are:',np.sqrt(x)
```

which gives me the following output:

```
Square roots of 4.0 are: 2.0
```

But I want to see `-2.0` in the answer as well, i.e. square roots of 4 will be +/- 2, not just only +2.

In a broader problem, I want to plot a function `f(x)=sqrt(x)`. I want to capture both the branches of the parabola in one shot. Right now the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0.0, 16.0, 0.2)
f = np.sqrt(x)
plt.plot(x, f)
plt.show()
```

which doesn't plot the values in the negative y-axis. Is it possible to do so without playing any trick (e.g. plotting second time assigning a minus to it)? It's not necessary that I have to use `numpy`.

Comment: Do you need to get it in some automated way? It's easy enough just to say `0 - np.sqrt(x)`.

Comment: Or just `-np.sqrt(x)`

Comment: Why not `x = np.linspace(-4.0, 4.0, 200); plt.plot(x**2, x)`?

Comment: Probably you didn't get the question. Is it possible to get both roots together. Suppose I have a function which has several squareroots in its definition. It's not possible to define them separately for each occurrence. People, please don't put negative votes unless you become sure about the stupidity of the question. At least wait for the comments back.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, because it might be a complicated function in future. I have provided a simplified example for testing. The actual function could be something like `f(x)=sqrt(x+sqrt(x)+x^(1/3))/(x+sqrt(2x))`. See my previous comment.

Comment: @hbaromega: It sounds as though the actual question you asked is different from the question you want an answer to. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Oh, not at all. The meaning of the question hasn't altered. Is it like, when we can't find an answer, we should blame the question (no offense intended)? To me, "it's not possible" could be an answer too. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think the OP is a bit confused about that: the square roots of 4 is +/-2, why `numpy.sqrt` just give the positive one?

But this is defined clearly in the function description:

```
Returns
-------
y : ndarray
    An array of the same shape as `x`, containing the positive
    square-root of each element in `x`.  ...
```

You can see this message by using `numpy.info(numpy.sqrt)` in the python shell.

Since every positive number has a pair square roots, if you want to print them all, just change you `print` statement to:

```
print 'Square roots of',x,'are: +/-',np.sqrt(x)
```

Comment: Sorry, this cannot be the answer. This is just a trick. I have modified my question to make the motivation more clear. Also see my comments above. I have asked for a possibility or if any function exists in some python libraries. If the answer is *No*, I won't mind to accept it.